# Template10 overwriting Windows Mobile System Header

Tags: template10

Doing some testing with Template10 I noticed that with say Hamburger Template that the windows system header/menu/whatever its called at the very top of my Windows Mobile 10 screen goes white and none of the icons (time, battery level, wifi signal etc) are visible when the light theme is used but they appear if I use the black theme.

If I use the Minimal Template then the system menu isn't visible with either the dark or light themes, its just a white band at the top.

Any idea on how to fix this?  I'm running a 950XL if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

That is a function of the theming and you need to account for it with the application being "mobile".  The so called "System Menu" is the StatusBar

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the OnInitializeAsync in the App.xaml.cs file

```
if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.Phone.PhoneContract", 1, 0))
{
    var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
    statusBar.BackgroundOpacity = 1;
}
```

and that seems to fix the problem.  Not sure how portable this is as I'm just targeting Windows Phone for this app so I haven't tried testing other platforms.